# Is there any possible use of using extern variable in a file that is not included in any other file?

Tags: c++, c, storage-class-specifier

I've encountered many examples on the web, that have `extern int x` in main.c, where the main function lies.

The only use of `extern` I'm aware of, is to make a declaration in another file, and use it in another file, after defining it.

Like :
a.h : `extern int x;`

a.c : `int x = 5;`

main.c : 
`#include "a.h" // and start using x`

The 1st case seems redundant to me.

So,
Is there any possible use of using an `extern` variable in a file that is not included in any other file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`extern` tells the compiler that `x` exists in a different module and should be linked from elsewhere.  Putting it in main.c directly just avoids pulling in a header (which would be included in-line anyways)

Just like in a header, `x` still needs to exist in another .c module where it *isn't* defined `extern`.

Comment: Wouldn't it work without the `extern`? I mean, if in a.c there is `int x = 8;` and in main.c I `include` a.c and start using x. Won't that work?

Comment: @learner no, that would break the one definition rule. `int x = 8;` is a definition, `extern int x;` is a declaration.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, There is no definition of x made in main.c.
 I just start using it. how is it beating that rule? Won't that work?

Comment: @ebyrob, When I #include that .c file, won't that definition get imported?

Comment: @ebyrob, Pratyush's answer shows the case when we have another variable with the same name in main.c. But if that weren't the case, is there a possible use of `extern` in main.c ?

Comment: @learner You don't generally include .c files only .h files.  Without a declaration in main.c you'd get variable undefined.  Hence the .h with extern, or just extern in the .c file.  a.c wouldn't be a separate module if you included it in main.c.

Comment: `extern` _can_ be a definition (although it usually isn't).  If he had written `extern int const x = 42;`, there would be no need to define `x` in another module.

Answer (score 2):

extern variable has basically two functions one is to use the variable in the other file and the other is to access global variables as in the following code.

```
int x=10;
int main()
{
     int x=20;
     cout<<x;             //refers to x=20
     if(x==20)
     {
            extern int x;
            cout<<x;      //refers to the global x that is x=10
     }
 }
```

Comment: Good example.  Using `::x` is probably preferable (and avoiding hiding the name entirely is even better), but this is certainly a use for `extern` which doesn't involve more than one source file.

Comment: yes James you are right `::x` is preferable. Well, this was just a use of `extern` variable.

Comment: And if you replace the `cout` with `printf`, you have code that works in both, C and C++, while `::x` of course only works in C++. Might be worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. Using `extern` in a file lets you use that variable in **that** file. It doesn't have to be included anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `extern` causes the object to have external linkage; to
instantiate a template with a object (and not a value or a type), the
object has to have external linkage (at least in C++03).  Most objects
defined in namespace scope have global linkage, but const objects don't.
So you have something like:

```
template <char const* n>
class Toto { /* ... */ };

char const n1[] = "abc";
Toto<n1> t1;    //  Illegal...

extern char const n2[] = "xyz";
Toto<n2> t2;    //  Legal...
```

It's sort of a special case, but it has led me (once or twice) to use
`extern` in an unnamed namespace in a source file.